# How to error handle in lambda function python

Tags: python, lambda, error-handling

I am new to python. Is there anyway I can raise error in Lambda function? I have a pyqt5 button that connect to a lambda function. I would like to catch the error in lambda function and show it to user. Is there anyway I can bring the message(string) out of the lambda function and then show it to user or is there anyway I can raise an error inside lambda function? I have a try/except in the place where lambda was apply. What I hope is when the lambda function have error and the error can be catch outside of the lambda function.

example:

```
def test1:
*****

def test2(a):
****

try:
   x=lambda(test2(test1))
except Exception as e:
   print(e)     <<< want it to go here.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you only assign a lambda function to a variable without any calling. In addition, the syntax for lambda seems to be wrong. You could change your code something like as follows:

```
def test1:
*****

def test2(a):
****

a_func = lambda x: test2(test1(x))

try:
   a_func(some_input)
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import boto3
import json
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # Fetch Datebase Identifier Environment variable
    DBinstance = os.environ['DBInstanceName']
    
    #create an Rds client
    context.rds_client = boto3.client('rds')
   
    # Describe instance
    response = context.rds_client.describe_db_instances(DBInstanceIdentifier=DBinstance )

    #Check the status of rds instance
    status = response['DBInstances'][0]['DBInstanceStatus']

    # If Rds Instance is in stopped stop, It will be started
    if status == "stopped":
        try:
        
            #Stopping the Rds instance
            response = context.rds_client.start_db_instance( DBInstanceIdentifier=DBinstance )
        
            #send logs to cloudwatch
            print ('Success :: Starting Rds instance:', DBinstance)
        
            #Logs to Lambda function Execution results
            return {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'message': "Starting Rds instance",
                'body': json.dumps(response, default=str)
            }
        
        except ClientError as e:
            #send logs to cloudwatch
            print(e)
            message = e
        
        #Logs to Lambda function Execution results
        return {
            'message': "Script execution completed. See Cloudwatch logs for complete output, but instance starting failed",
            'body': json.dumps(message, default=str)
        }
    # if Rds instance is in running state, It will be stopped
    elif status == "available":
        try: 
            #Stopping the Rds instance
            response = context.rds_client.stop_db_instance( DBInstanceIdentifier=DBinstance )
        
            #send logs to cloudwatch
            print ('Success :: Stopping Rds instance:', DBinstance)
        
            #Logs to Lambda function Execution results
            return {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'message': "Stopping Rds instance",
                'body': json.dumps(response, default=str)
            }
        except ClientError as e:
            #send logs to cloudwatch
            print(e)
            message = e
        
        #Logs to Lambda function Execution results
        return {
            'message': "Script execution completed. See Cloudwatch logs for complete output, but instance stopping failed",
            'body': json.dumps(message, default=str)
        }
```